# Using SendMessage in python to set text in foreground window

Tags: python, c, windows, winapi

We have an old, legacy database that needs input from another system. SendInput method of data input into database forms is slow and unreliable, setting clipboard and then ^v is not reliable either (I have no idea why, but database interface is very old, early 2000s). After a lot of fiddling I discovered that using SendMessage to set text and then sending VK_RETURN is fast (much faster than SendInput/keybd_event) and reliable with our database. Now this code in plain C works:

```
    HWND fghwnd = GetForegroundWindow();
    DWORD threadId = GetWindowThreadProcessId(fghwnd, NULL);
    DWORD myId = GetCurrentThreadId();
    if (AttachThreadInput(myId, threadId, true)) {
        HWND ctrl = GetFocus();
        SendMessage(ctrl, WM_SETTEXT, 0, (LPARAM) sendbuf); // TESTING
        PostMessage(ctrl, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_RETURN, 0);
        PostMessage(ctrl, WM_KEYUP, VK_RETURN, 0);
        AttachThreadInput(myId, threadId, false);
    } else {
        printf("\nError: AttachThreadInput failure!\n");
    }
```

But this one in python does not:

```
    foregroundHwnd = win32gui.GetForegroundWindow()
    foregroundThreadID = win32process.GetWindowThreadProcessId(foregroundHwnd)[0]
    ourThreadID = win32api.GetCurrentThreadId()
    if foregroundThreadID != ourThreadID:
        win32process.AttachThreadInput(foregroundThreadID, ourThreadID, True)
        focus_whd = win32gui.GetFocus()
        win32gui.SendMessage(focus_whd, win32con.WM_SETTEXT, None, "test text")
        win32gui.PostMessage(focus_whd, win32con.WM_KEYDOWN, win32con.VK_RETURN, None)
        win32gui.PostMessage(focus_whd, win32con.WM_KEYUP, win32con.VK_RETURN, None)
        win32process.AttachThreadInput(foregroundThreadID, ourThreadID, False)
```

The trouble is, most of our new logic in python. I turned that C code into a small python module and it works, but as result now I've got dependency on Microsoft's huge compiler and a lot of fiddling with module building. I'd like to have a python-only solution.

Any ideas why this python code does not work? These system calls look the same...

Comment: You've got no error checking. Perhaps one of the API calls fails.

Comment: It is recommended to check the return value of `focus_whd`, which returns 0 in my Python compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, AttachThreadInput failed. According to the comment here https://toster.ru/q/79336 win32process.GetWindowThreadProcessId returns wrong value, ctypes must be used. This code works:

```
"""
Fast "paste" implemented via calls to Windows internals, sends parameter
string and RETURN after that

Usage:

from paste import paste
paste("test")

"""

import time
import random
import string
from ctypes import windll
import ctypes
import win32con

def random_string(string_length=10):
    """Generate a random string of fixed length """
    letters = string.ascii_lowercase
    return ''.join(random.choice(letters) for i in range(string_length))

ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER = 87

def paste(text_to_paste):
    """Fast "paste" using WM_SETTEXT method + Enter key"""
    current_hwnd = windll.user32.GetForegroundWindow()
    current_thread_id = windll.kernel32.GetCurrentThreadId()
    thread_process_id = windll.user32.GetWindowThreadProcessId(current_hwnd, None)
    if thread_process_id != current_thread_id:
        res = windll.user32.AttachThreadInput(thread_process_id, current_thread_id, True)
        # ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER means that the two threads are already attached.
        if res == 0 and ctypes.GetLastError() != ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER:
            print("WARN: could not attach thread input to thread {0} ({1})"
                .format(thread_process_id, ctypes.GetLastError()))
            return
        focus_whd = windll.user32.GetFocus()
        windll.user32.SendMessageW(focus_whd, win32con.WM_SETTEXT, None, text_to_paste)
        windll.user32.PostMessageW(focus_whd, win32con.WM_KEYDOWN, win32con.VK_RETURN, None)
        windll.user32.PostMessageW(focus_whd, win32con.WM_KEYUP, win32con.VK_RETURN, None)
        res = windll.user32.AttachThreadInput(thread_process_id, current_thread_id, True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    time.sleep(5) # time to switch to the target
    # paste random 150 char string
    paste(random_string(150))
```

Comment: Isn't the last `AttachThreadInput` supposed to detach thread with `False`?